# React hooks not giving updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, publish-subscribe, codesandbox

Please access the code at below link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/notification-co637

Now in file : Notificaitons.js. :
#1 :My comp. is rendered twice, Why?
#2 : When i click on button,i am publishing the event but my localState is always having initial value. My array size is always one.

What i am doing wrong here?

I wanted to do this using hooks.I am able to do it in class based comp.

Comment: I didnt understand what you need to do, when you click on button "Get user" and "Check comp state' what should happen ?

Comment: Please put properly formatted code *here*, not out at a link.  Also make sure it's the minimal code needed to ask the question (but still complete)

Comment: Notificaitons.js. : notifications that are appearing in the UI should be multiple as soon as you will click in getUser button but its not getting done.I am not able to understand the reason for this.

Comment: Show formatted code *here* if you want an answer.  Yes, it's extra work for you.  That's the cost of being courteous to those who may take from *their own time* to help you.